# rsync filters failing when executed with python subprocess.run()

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, rsync

I have a slightly complicated `rsync` command that needs to be executed at regular intervals by a python program.

```
enter code here
```

The command executes correctly from the command line, but when run with `subprocess.run()`, the include/exclude filters seem to be ignored.

The command is meant to sync certain data files between a pair of Raspberry Pi3's over `ssh`. The Pi's are running `Python 3.5.2` and `rsync 3.11` under Raspbian `jessie`.

**Here's my test code executed from an ipython session.**

```
In [3]: def testrsync():
   ...:     from subpro`enter code here`cess import run
   ...:     cmd = ("rsync -avzhe ssh -i --include='*.zip' --include='data.csv' "
   ...:            "--exclude='*' pi@192.168.1.122:/home/pi/pgcdata/ "
   ...:            "/tmp/pgcdata")
   ...:     cmdlist = cmd.split()
   ...:     print(cmd)
   ...:     ret  = run(cmdlist, shell=False)
   ...:     print(ret)
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: testrsync()
rsync -avzhe ssh -i --include='*.zip' --include='data.csv' --exclude='*' pi@192.168.1.122:/home/pi/pgcdata/ /tmp/pgcdata
receiving incremental file list
created directory /tmp/pgcdata
cd+++++++++ ./
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-24.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-25.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-26.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-27.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-28.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-29.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-30.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-31.csv
>f+++++++++ data.csv
>f+++++++++ four-hour-plot.csv
>f+++++++++ one-day-plot.csv
>f+++++++++ seven-day-plot.csv
>f+++++++++ thirty-day-plot.csv

sent 312 bytes  received 731.54K bytes  162.63K bytes/sec
total size is 35.49M  speedup is 48.49
CompletedProcess(args=['rsync', '-avzhe', 'ssh', '-i', "--include='*.zip'", "--include='data.csv'", "--exclude='*'", 'pi@192.168.1.122:/home/pi/pgcdata/', '/tmp/pgcdata'], returncode=0)
```

**The last four files above should NOT have been copied. If I empty the target directory, copy the printed rsync command and run it as a shell command, the filtering occurs and only the desired files are copied.**

```
In [5]: !rm -rf /tmp/pgcdata/

In [6]: !rsync -avzhe ssh -i --include='*.zip' --include='data.csv' --exclude='*' pi@192.168.1.122:/home/pi/pgcdata
   ...: / /tmp/pgcdata
receiving incremental file list
created directory /tmp/pgcdata
cd+++++++++ ./
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-24.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-25.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-26.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-27.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-28.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-29.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data-2018-01-30.csv.zip
>f+++++++++ data.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the single quotes around the filter patterns.  They're necessary to prevent the shell from expanding the patterns and the shell strips away the quotes before rsync sees them.

`Subprocess.run` with `shell=False` doesn't strip the quotes and `rsync`, bless its little heart, doesn't complain. So the patterns end up having no effect and everything gets copied.

The problem is cured when I change the command string to:

```
cmd = ("rsync -avzhe ssh -i --include=*.zip --include=data.csv "
       "--exclude=* pi@192.168.1.122:/home/pi/pgcdata/ "
       "/tmp/pgcdata")
```